# Close Quick Settings Panel after click the Quick Setting tile in android

Tags: android, android-service, android-app-quick-setting

My app has a Tile Service.

After clicked on that tile, the `onClick` function run perfectly fine, but I wanted to close the quick setting panel, is there anyway to achive that goal?

[image: QS panel image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`startActivityAndCollapse`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/quicksettings/TileService.html#startActivityAndCollapse(android.content.Intent)) instead of `startActivity` in your onClick function in TileService which will collapse the QS panel.

Comment: What if i do not want to start an activity but a foreground service?

Answer (score 1):

Improvement to the right answer to resolve compatibility issue with old versions on Android:

```kotlin
Intent(this, DestinationActivity::class.java).also {
    it.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
    TileServiceCompat.startActivityAndCollapse(
        this@MyTileService,
        PendingIntentActivityWrapper(
            this@MyTileService,
            0,
            it,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT,
            true
        )
    )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just show dialog and dismiss it , if your query is just closing quick settings soon after pressing
`val dialog = Dialog(applicationContext) showDialog(dialog) dialog.dismiss()`